# what is the best practice to set up DbContext in StructureMap for console app?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, structuremap, poco, dbcontext

I use StructureMap, EF 4.1/POCO. 
Console app supposes to run 2 consequent operations upon some set of data, lets say operation1 and operation2. I set DbContext up as an singleton. This causes problem in operation2 as operation1 left some trash in its DbContext that prevent operation2 works well. In the same time I can not set up DbContext as 'per call' coz operation1 uses 2 repositories sharing the same DbContext passing through their constructor. So ideally I need reinitialize/reset/cleanup DbContext before operation2. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use two different contexts. There is no better solution to reset context then creating a new one. If you are fighting with your current architecture simply improve it to support new scenario. Instead of passing context instance pass a context factory which will be able to create you as many context instances as you need. Same with repositories - you can have factory to create a new repository instances on demand.

Edit with example:

Let's suppose that you are using [EFv4.1 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825). It offers new interface `IDbContexFactory<TContext>`. You can define your class this way:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<IYourContext> _factory;

    public YourClass(IDbContextFactory<IYourContext> factory) 
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Operation1() 
    {
        using (IYourContext context = _factory.Create()) 
        {
            RepositoryA repository = new RepositoryA(context);
            RepositoryB repository = new RepositoryB(context);
            ...
        }
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        using (IYourContext context = _factory.Create()) 
        {
            RepositoryA repository = new RepositoryA(context);
            RepositoryB repository = new RepositoryB(context);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This was example where you pass factory for context but you can do the same for repository if you want to.

Comment: It is equal to change DbContext's life-cycle to 'per call' and manage its instance manually on service level like in your example. I used to manage all service and repository objects life cycle via StructureMap, I have no 'new' statements for services in my code. Other than that it introduces additional dependency: service is aware of DbContext derived class. So too many changes in design are supposed to be done in the case, need to consider it carefully. Thanks for your idea anyway.