# ASP.NET MVC 3 or 4 - how to handle many DBs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

I have a case  where each customer has his own DB - What i would like to do is for this to happen automatically eg when Autofac creates the controller it looks up the clientId and then gets the connection string

The following gets the string

```
public class ModuleContextProvider : IModuleContextProvider
{
    IModuleContext context;



    public IModuleContext GetContext(int moduleId)
    {
        if ( context == null) 
        {

            //get module.
            var rep = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IModuleRepository>();
            var module = rep.GetById(moduleId);
            context = GetContext(module);
        }

        return context;

    }

    public IModuleContext GetContext(Model.Module module)
    {


        if ( context == null) 
        {

            //get module.
            var rep = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IModuleRepository>();
            context = new ModuleContext(module.DBConnection); 
            if ( context == null) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could nto create DB COntext" );
        }

                 return context;
    }
}
```

but how do i get it into the Controllers so everyone does not need to worry about it each time  , i have the following but obviously to create the repositry i need the context.

```
    public CategoryController(ICommandBus commandBus, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
    {
        this.commandBus = commandBus;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }
```

Is it possible to use a ROute eg //Controller/ModuleId/Method  and then somehow get this from the Url ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: The real issue here I think is how to keep pushing the connection string around ( in this case in the form of the module) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs this ..

I stored it in the cookie and retrieve in the controller as follows

```
    IModuleWorldRepository moduleWorldRepository;

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        moduleWorldRepository = GetModuleWorldRepository();

    }

    IModuleWorldRepository GetModuleWorldRepository()
    {

        UserRunTimeInfo user = (UserRunTimeInfo)User.Identity;
        var context = contextProvider.GetContext(user.CurrentModuleId);
        return new ModuleWorldRepository(context);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using the IDbContextFactory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506876(v=vs.103).aspx

[what is the best practice to set up DbContext in StructureMap for console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112201/what-is-the-best-practice-to-set-up-dbcontext-in-structuremap-for-console-app)

It was added in the EF 4.1 Update 1.

Not sure if that will help your problem, but either way it's good to know.

Comment: This is similar to my  ModuleContextProvider but it doesnt answer how the Factory creates it. I need something like a moduleId to tell what connection string to use. So options i can see are

Comment: 1  Put the "Module" which has the value  in the url via routing somewhere and then extract - not sure how to extract this.  2. Pass it as a parameter on the URL , again not sure how to get it into the above factory   3. Introduce session state  4.pass it on every method call ( very ugly)